# Geodesic equation in terms of four velocity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, calculus, geodesics

I am trying to show that for timelike paths, we can write the geodesic equation in terms of the four-velocity $U^\mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}$ as
$$U^\lambda\nabla_\lambda U^\mu=0.$$

In other words, substituting $U^ \mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}$ into the above equation should produce the affinely parameterised geodesic equation

$$\frac{d^2x^\mu}{d\tau^2}+\Gamma^\mu_{\rho\lambda}\frac{dx^\rho}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\lambda}{d\tau}=0.$$

Performing the substitution, I got instead

$$U^\lambda(\partial_\lambda U^\mu +\Gamma^\mu_{\rho\lambda}U^\rho)=0$$
$$U^\lambda\partial_\lambda U^\mu +\Gamma^\mu_{\rho\lambda}U^\rho U^\lambda=0$$
$$\frac{dx^\lambda}{d\tau} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\lambda} \frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}+\Gamma^\mu_{\rho\lambda}\frac{dx^\rho}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\lambda}{d\tau}=0$$
$$\frac{dx^\lambda}{d\tau}\frac{d}{d\tau}  \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^\lambda}+\Gamma^\mu_{\rho\lambda}\frac{dx^\rho}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\lambda}{d\tau}=0$$

$$\frac{dx^\lambda}{d\tau}\frac{d}{d\tau}  \delta^\mu_\lambda+\Gamma^\mu_{\rho\lambda}\frac{dx^\rho}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\lambda}{d\tau}=0$$

$$\Gamma^\mu_{\rho\lambda}\frac{dx^\rho}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\lambda}{d\tau}=0$$

where I used $\frac{d}{d\tau}  \delta^\mu_\lambda=0$ in the last line since $\delta^\mu_\lambda$ is a constant.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are confusing your self, because you use $x^\mu$ to represent both your path, and as a general coordinate. Try introducing a different symbol for your path, e.g. $\gamma^\mu$.

Comment: @mmeent That makes sense, I am indeed confusing those two variables..

Comment: Said differently, a derivative wrt $\tau$ does not commute with a spatial derivative. This is because d/dt commutes with d/dx, but $\tau$ is related to t by the Lorentz factor $\gamma$ which is a function of velocities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{equation} 
\frac{\mathrm d x^\lambda}{\mathrm  d\tau} \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\lambda} \frac{\mathrm d x^\mu}{\mathrm  d\tau}\right]=\frac{\mathrm d x^\lambda}{\mathrm  d\tau}\left[\frac{\partial }{\partial\tau}\left(\frac{\mathrm d x^\mu}{\mathrm  d\tau}\right) \frac{\partial\tau}{\partial x^\lambda}\right]=\frac{\partial }{\partial\tau}\left(\frac{\mathrm d x^\mu}{\mathrm  d\tau}\right) \underbrace{\frac{\partial\tau}{\partial x^\lambda}\frac{\mathrm d x^\lambda}{\mathrm  d\tau}}_{1}=\frac{\mathrm d^2 x^\mu}{\mathrm  d\tau^2} 
\tag{01}\label{01} 
\end{equation}